# Retrieving members from a cluster using R

Tags: r

How could I get the elements from each cluster(hierarchial clustering) and is there any package in R to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

you can do that using cutree():

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, h = 50)
cutree(hc, h = 50)
```

Comment: I am getting this error " Error in rect(m[which[n]] + 0.66, par("usr")[3L], m[which[n] + 1] + 0.33,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet when I use rect.hclust.How to solve this error.

Comment: you need to plot the dendrogram first and then use rect.

Comment: Had the same issue in R Markdown. You have to put them on separate lines and then highlight them both and run them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "Error in rect(m[which[n]] + 0.66, par("usr")[3L], m[which[n] + 1] + 0.33, : plot.new has not been called yet" drawing the dendrogram as follow:

```
USA.tree <- hclust(dist(USAarrest)
plot(hclust(dist(USAarrest))) #if I use plot(USA.tree) returns an error
x <- rect.hclust(USA.tree, k=3, border="red")
# x <- rect.hclust(USA.tree, h = 50, which = c(2,7), border = 3:4)
x
```